# Rxphoto: How .requestUri(context, TypeRequest.GALLERY) whit RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Rxphoto: How can i use .requestUri(context, TypeRequest.GALLERY) whit RxJava?

Link ti library: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3870#!description

And how then upload this file using Retrofit2? Some examples?

Thanks!

Comment: try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40968894/3629732)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this this

```
RxPhoto.requestUri(context, TypeRequest.GALLERY)
    flatMap(new Func1<Uri, Observable<Response>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Response> call(Uri uri) {

            File file = new File(uriString);
            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
            RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "upload_test");
            return service.postImage(body, name); 


        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response response) {

        }
    });
```

The Retrofit call service

```
interface Service {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/")
    Observable<Response> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image,@Part("name") RequestBody name);
}
```

**Note: Service should be multipart request compulsory in Server Side**

Comment: @OlegMiroshin new File(uri.getPath());

Comment: Yes, I realized at the same time with your comment
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using this code i have little problems:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970207/rxjava-unable-to-create-call-adapter-for-rx-observable-error