# RxJava: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable error

Tags: android, rx-java

What i do:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @Multipart
        @POST("/android/upload/index.php")
        Observable<Response> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image,   @Part("name") RequestBody name);
}
```

Model:

```
public interface Model {
 Observable<Response> postImage(MultipartBody.Part image, RequestBody name);
}
```

Impl:

```
public class ModelImpl implements Model {
    ApiModule apiModule = ApiModule.getInstance();
 @Override
    public Observable<Response> postImage(MultipartBody.Part image, RequestBody name) {
        return apiModule.getApi().postImage(image,name);
    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
RxPhoto.requestUri(context, TypeRequest.GALLERY)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Uri, Observable<Response>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Response> call(Uri uri) {

                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
                RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "upload_test");
                return model.postImage(body, name);


            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        Log.d(tag, "error:" + e);

                    }

                });
```

I have error:

*error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable
                                                                  for method ApiInterface.postImage*

**UPD:**

I change interface and others to :

```
Observable<uploadAnswer>


    public class uploadAnswer {

        @SerializedName("success")
        @Expose
        private String success;

        public String getSuccess() {
            return this.success;
        }

    }
```

after that my first error gone, now i have this error:

*java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:52214: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)*

What to do?

**UPD2:**

I use this function to get file uri:

```
public String getRealPathFromURIPath(Uri contentURI) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(idx);
        }
    }
```

After that i have this error (is it mean, that i'm right ?? ):

*error:android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException*

**UPD3:**

My short code:

```
RxPhoto.requestUri(context,TypeRequest.GALLERY)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Uri>(){

                    @Override
                    public void call(Uri uri) {

                        Log.d(tag, "up => " + uri);

                        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
                        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "upload_test");

                        //model.postImage(body, name);

                        GetDataSubscription = model.postImage(body,name)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe();

                    }

                })
                .subscribe();
```

I still have errors:

*E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: info.masterskaya.om.near, PID: 8348
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
                                                                            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable
                                                                            for method ApiInterface.postImage
                                                                            at rx.Observable$26.onError(Observable.java:8524)
                                                                            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
                                                                            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:71)
                                                                            at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:189)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onNext(OperatorDoOnEach.java:82)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:215)
                                                                            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                                                                                ... 9 more
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable
                                                                            for method ApiInterface.postImage
                                                                            at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:695)
                                                                            at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:233)
                                                                            at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:159)
                                                                            at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
                                                                            at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
                                                                            at $Proxy0.postImage(Native Method)
                                                                            at info.masterskaya.om.near.mvp.model.ModelImpl.postImage(ModelImpl.java:53)
                                                                            at info.masterskaya.om.near.mvp.presenter.PresenterImpl$1.call(PresenterImpl.java:133)
                                                                            at info.masterskaya.om.near.mvp.presenter.PresenterImpl$1.call(PresenterImpl.java:119)
                                                                            at rx.Observable$11.onNext(Observable.java:4820)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onNext(OperatorDoOnEach.java:80)
                                                                                ... 11 more
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response must be parameterized as Response or Response
                                                                            at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.getCallAdapter(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:119)
                                                                            at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.get(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:105)
                                                                            at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:217)
                                                                            at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:201)
                                                                            at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:231)
                                                                                ... 20 more
                                                                         Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri.class
                                                                            at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:189)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onNext(OperatorDoOnEach.java:82)
                                                                                ... 11 more*

if i change my interface to:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/upload/index.php")
    Observable<String> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

I have this trace:

*E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: info.masterskaya.om.near, PID: 8618
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
                                                                            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:60)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: /document/image:34: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                            at rx.Observable$26.onError(Observable.java:8524)
                                                                            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
                                                                            at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:264)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:207)
                                                                            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:34: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
                                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:78)
                                                                            at okio.Okio.source(Okio.java:163)
                                                                            at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:117)
                                                                            at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:171)
                                                                            at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:113)
                                                                            at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:186)
                                                                            at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
                                                                            at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
                                                                            at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
                                                                            at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
                                                                            at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:80)
                                                                            at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
                                                                            at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
                                                                            at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
                                                                            at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
                                                                            at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:233)
                                                                            at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:225)
                                                                            at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8741)
                                                                            at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
                                                                            at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                         Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
                                                                        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
                                                                        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78) 
                                                                        at okio.Okio.source(Okio.java:163) 
                                                                        at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:117) 
                                                                        at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:171) 
                                                                        at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:113) 
                                                                        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:186) 
                                                                        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
                                                                        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160) 
                                                                        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57) 
                                                                        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174) 
                                                                        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171) 
                                                                        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:80) 
                                                                        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211) 
                                                                        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76) 
                                                                        at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) 
                                                                        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152) 
                                                                        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138) 
                                                                        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:233) 
                                                                        at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:225) 
                                                                        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8741) 
                                                                        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) 
                                                                        at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)*
```

**UPD4:**

I have some results.

Interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/upload/index.php")
Observable<Void> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

Main function:

```
RxPhoto.requestUri(context,TypeRequest.GALLERY)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(new Action1<Uri>(){

                    @Override
                    public void call(Uri uri) {

                        Log.d(tag, "up => " + uri);
                        Log.d(tag, "getPath => " + getPath(context,uri));

                        String URL = getPath(context,uri);

                        File file = new File( URL+"" );

                        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);
                        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "upload_test");

                        GetDataSubscription = model.postImage(body,name)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .subscribe();

                    }

                })
                .subscribe();
```

/~~~~~~~/

```
getPath(context,uri)
```

i find [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20559418/7184505)

Now i have server error:

> 12-09 05:37:55.760 10230-10372/*** D/OkHttp:
>   --857d62de-296c-4d23-8683-92b3b340a658 12-09 05:37:55.760 10230-10372/** D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="upload"; filename="IMG_20161206_092257.jpg" 12-09 05:37:55.760
>   10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data 12-09
>   05:37:55.760 10230-10372/*** D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 26188
>
> ...
>
> 12-09 05:37:55.770 10230-10372/*** D/OkHttp:
>   --857d62de-296c-4d23-8683-92b3b340a658 12-09 05:37:55.770 10230-10372/** D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
>   12-09 05:37:55.770 10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp:
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 12-09 05:37:55.770 10230-10372/**
>   D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8 12-09
>   05:37:55.770 10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 11 12-09
>   05:37:55.770 10230-10372/** D/OkHttp: upload_test 12-09 05:37:55.770
>   10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp: --857d62de-296c-4d23-8683-92b3b340a658--
>   12-09 05:37:55.770 10230-10372/** D/OkHttp: --> END POST (26620-byte
>   body) 12-09 05:37:55.800 10230-10334/ **D/GoogleCertificatesImpl:
>   Fetched 363 Google certificates 12-09 05:37:56.340 10230-10230/**
>   I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread. 12-09 05:37:56.390 10230-10372/
>   **D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://www.**/upload/index.php (604ms) 12-09
>   05:37:56.390 10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2016 10:37:56
>   GMT 12-09 05:37:56.390 10230-10372/** D/OkHttp: Server: Apache 12-09
>   05:37:56.390 10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept-Encoding 12-09
>   05:37:56.390 10230-10372/** D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8 12-09 05:37:56.390 10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp: X-Cache:
>   MISS from t7.**.ru 12-09 05:37:56.390 10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp:
>   X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from t7.**.ru:6666 12-09 05:37:56.390
>   10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive 12-09 05:37:56.390
>   10230-10372/** D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1481279876016 12-09
>   05:37:56.390 10230-10372/ **D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis:
>   1481279876396 12-09 05:37:56.390 10230-10372/*** D/OkHttp: {"result":
>   "fail"} 12-09 05:37:56.390 10230-10372/*** D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
>   (18-byte body)

Server:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "up/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo '{"result": "success"}';
    } else{
        echo '{"result": "fail"}';
    }
 ?>
```

**UPD5:**

I done this f*cking upload!

php test code:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));

    $file_path = ROOT_DIR . "";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo '{"result": "success"}';
    } else{
        echo '{"result": "fail"}';
    }
 ?>
```

All my problems was with right uri on device. Try API 16,19 and 24 all successfull

Comment: you resolved this error ?

Comment: Thank you for your support and interest in my question,
I used to debug:

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: that one bad option you can use Schedulers for NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: I try to use example from Retrofit tutorials, where used 

File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

But unsuccessfully, now i'm trying two steps:

-get correct file from gallery
-upload with retrofit

but i think, that the main problem is in this error:
Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable<retrofit2.Response>
                                                                  for method ApiInterface.postImage

Comment: StrictMode only is bad others good only

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the following part:

```
Observable<Response>
```

Response **always** needs a specified body type. It looks like your response don't have a body, so you should replace it with this:

```
Observable<Result<Void>>
```

...and request the response using `result.response()`

Comment: THIS! Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Include call adapter factory, if you forget it.

RxJava2: `compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'`

RxJava : `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'`

**Edit:**

Ok, is because you need to convert `multipart`, not `text`, so change will be here:

```
RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "upload_test");
```

Also mediatype should be the same

```
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);`
```

For more Informations take a look [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server).

Comment: In this error i think is because you have added two lines of same library. Check your expected response from observable. I think there is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the `name` parameter is only String, I think the api should be called like:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @Multipart
        @POST("/android/upload/index.php")
        Observable<Response> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image,   @Part("name") String name);
}
```